# How to covert CRLF to LF

Tags: npm, linefeed

I am trying to create a  npm run build for a project using React and Webpack among other components that I cloned from Github.  However the error message I keep getting is

Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF' (linebreak-style) at src\index.jsx:60:8:

What can I do to fix this and create a successful run build?